# Problems changing the flags of a QWidget

Tags: qt, events, qwidget, flags

I have a QWidget as the child of another within my application. The task consists of putting the internal widget in full screen mode and being able to see it again in normal mode with the same button. This partly I have managed to do it in the following way:

```
if(!isFullScreen())
{
   setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::Window);
   showFullScreen();
}
else
{
   setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::Window);
   showNormal();
   activateWindow();
}
```

The problem arises when you return to see the widget in normal mode. Things that happen:

- The mouse cursor stays with pointing hand cursor.
- The button to change mode remains in hover state (the background color is changed when the mouse is over)
- Passing the mouse through other widget controls does not change its appearance

I have to click on the widget to fix the behavior. It's as if the widget did not receive events of any kind or something like that. I tried calling setFocus () and it did not work. I have also tried to send an event by hand in the following way but it has not worked either:

```
QMouseEvent my_event(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPointF (0, 0), Qt :: NoButton, 0, 0);
QApplication::sendEvent(this, & my_event);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your issue on Xubuntu with Qt5.9.4.

However I did the same in my last job, and it worked correctly on all platforms. It was something like this, I think:

```
if(!isFullScreen())
{
    setParent(0);
    showFullScreen();
}
else
{
    orignalParentLayout->addWidget(this); // better: insert at correct position
    showNormal();
}
```

For this you have to add some knowledge about the parent's layout though. You could try to detect that info before going into full screen mode, but it is probably not worth the effort.

You could also try:

```
if(!isFullScreen())
{
    logicalParent = parentWidget();
    setParent(0);
    showFullScreen();
}
else
{
    setParent(logicalParent);
    showNormal();
}
```

If you have no layout. You might also want to store the geometry before going to full screen.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for answering.

The problem I find with your solution is that if you remove the parent from the widget, a new window is created outside of the application's environment. What I want is a behavior similar to the "print preview" of Word for example, a full screen mode within my application.

Comment: The additional window will either be in full screen or not exist at all. But that is the same with your code, only that you trick Qt into treating it as a window while I cleanly move it out and back into the object structure.

Comment: With my code, the full screen window is inside of the application's environment, however, with your solution a new navigable window is created for example from the Alt + Tab option, and that is not what I want

Comment: For me, so does yours. You can try to something like `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool);` which hides it from Alt+Tab. It is still a separate window though, and both can be accessed. If you want to actually really only have one window at all, hide the original or add the widget as topmost opaque overlay widget to the toplevel window and show that in full screen mode. Be a little creative.